# How to read a data in dataset using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new in jQuery and would like to know how can i write this statement

```
selector.dataset.position = position;
```

in jQuery? in CSS I've defined class 'super' with data-position = '1'

jQuery

```
var position = 0;
var selector = $('.selector')
```

HTML

```
 <section class="super">
    <div class="selector">
        foo
    </div>

    <div class="size">
        Test 1
    </div>

    <div class="size">
        Test 2
    </div>

    <div class="size">
        Test 4
    </div>

    <div class="size">
        Test 4
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

`$('.selector').data('position', position);`